# Python 'except' fall-through

Tags: python-2.7, exception, try-catch

I was wondering if you could re-raise a (specific) caught exception and have it caught by a later (general) except in the same try-except. As an example, I want to do something with a specific IOError, but if its not the expected IOError then the exception should be handled like any other error. What I initially tried:

```
try:
    raise IOError()
except IOError as ioerr:
    if ioerr.errno == errno.ENOENT:
        # do something with the expected err
    else:
        # continue with the try-except - should be handled like any other error
        raise
except Exception as ex:
    # general error handling code
```

However, this doesn't work: the raise re-raises the exception outside the context of the try-except.
What would be the pythonic way of writing this to get the desired exception 'fall-through' behaviour?

(I'm aware there was a proposed 'conditional except' that wasn't implemented, which could've solved this)

Comment: So you want to be able to go from the `except IOError` block to the `except Exception` block? As far as I'm aware that is not possible, only one `except` block (or the `else` block) runs for a given `try`. You could wrap the whole thing in another `try`, removing the inner `except Exception`, which would mean all but the specifically-handled `IOError`s end up in the outer `try`'s `except`s.

Comment: This is what I want to do, and I was worried that only a single except would be possible. I'm hoping for a more elegant solution that something like nested else's/code duplication

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you ultimately want it to catch everything, make it do that. Catch first, sieve later. ;)

```
try:
    raise IOError()
except Exception as ex:
    if isinstance(ex, IOError) and ex.errno == errno.ENOENT:
        # do something with the expected err
    # do the rest
```

Comment: You can add an `else` statement to `# do the rest` only if your expectation failed.

Answer (score 4):

I am not an expert in writing pythonically, but I think one obvious approach (if you know that you're expecting one particular kind of exception), would be to use nested exception handling:

```
try:
    try:
        raise IOError()
    except IOError as ioerr:
        if ioerr.errno == errno.ENOENT:
            # do something with the expected err
        else:
            # pass this on to higher up exception handling
            raise

except Exception as ex:
    # general error handling code
```

I know in your comment that you didn't want nested else's -- I don't know if nested exception handling is as bad in your book, but at the very least you can avoid code duplication.

Comment: This is a great approach, it really seems obvious once you've seen it. Very cool idea!

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm working on the same here, and after reviewing the available solutions, I'm going to go with catching the parent exception, and then testing for specifics.  In my case I'm working with the dns module.

```
try:
    answer = self._resolver.query(name, 'NS')
except dns.exception.DNSException, e:  #Superclass of exceptions tested for
    if isinstance(e, dns.resolver.NXDOMAIN):
        #Do Stuff
    elif isinstance(e, dns.resolver.NoAnswer):
        # Do other stuff
    else:
        # Do default stuff
```