# Is this a Pythonic way to handle custom errors?

Tags: python-2.7, custom-error-handling

```
try:
    try:
        # important operations
    except Exception:
        raise CustomException

    # general operations

except CustomException:
    # "Custom logs"
except Exception:
    # "General exception occurred"
```

I'm using `Python 2.7`.
I also considered the answer of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33217472/python-except-fall-through), but I feel that is not the proper way to do it, since you use "except Exception" as a general box for other exceptions.

For CustomException I intend something like:

```
class CustomException(Exception):
    """This exception will be raised when..."""
```

Comment: What do you mean by pythonic? `try/except` statements is the way to handle exceptions. You can define your [own exception](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/user-defined-exception) and catch it with `except [insert custom exception name here]`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with this pattern if ou happen to need it.  And I can imagine mechanisms where that would be useful.

Just take care to proper instantiate your exceptions - `raise CustomException()` vs just `raise CustomException`

Also, if you where using a newer version of the language, you could use `raise from`:

```
...
except Exception as inner_error:
    raise CustomException from inner_error
...
```

That would correctly wrap all the information from the general exception in your CustomException instance.